# Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a complete measure space. Show $\mathcal{J}:=\{A\in\mathcal{M}|\mu(A^{c})=0\}\cup\{\emptyset\}\}$ is a topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a complete measure space. Let $\mathcal{J}:=\{A\in\mathcal{M}|\mu(A^{c})=0\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$

1) Prove that $\mathcal{J}$ is a topology on $X$

Any thoughts on how to start? (We have not had topology course yet..but our instructor says it should not be too difficult, I googled the axioms)

I would appreciate help with this problem.

1) Since $X\in\mathcal{M}$ and $X\subset X$ , $\mu(X)=0$ from the completeness of the measure space, but then $0=\mu(X)=\mu(\emptyset^{c})\Rightarrow \emptyset\in J$

is this ok so far? Seems a bit pointless to do that as by the def of $\mathcal{J}$ the empty set is already there

2) how to show that the entire space $X\in\mathcal{J}$?

3) $\mathcal{J}$ is closed under any union of sets

4) closed under finite interesections

Comment: If $\mu(X) = 0$, then $\mathcal{J}$ is the entire power set of $X$, so the discrete topology. Assume $\mu(X) \neq 0$ for something interesting. You get $X \in \mathcal{J}$ from $\mu(X^c) = \mu(\varnothing) = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\emptyset \in \mathcal J$ by hypothesis.

Since $X^\complement = \emptyset$, we have $\mu(X^\complement) = 0$ and $X \in \mathcal J$.

Let $A, B \in \mathcal J$. If any of $A$ or $B$ is empty, then $A \cap B = \emptyset \in \mathcal J$. Otherwise, suppose $A, B \ne \emptyset$. This means $\mu(A^\complement) = 0$, $\mu(B^\complement) = 0$. Since $(A \cap B)^\complement = A^\complement \cup B^\complement$, it follows that
$$\mu\left((A \cap B)^\complement\right) = \mu(A^\complement \cup B^\complement) \le \mu(A^\complement) + \mu(B^\complement) = 0.$$

Thus, $A \cap B \in \mathcal J$. By induction, the intersection of any finite collection of sets in $\mathcal J$ is also in $\mathcal J$.

Let $\{A_\alpha\} \subset \mathcal J$. If $A_\alpha = \emptyset$ for all $\alpha$, then $\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha = \emptyset \in \mathcal J$. Otherwise, suppose $A_\beta \ne \mathcal \emptyset$ for some $\beta$. We have

$$
\left(\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha\right)^\complement = \bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha^\complement \subset A_\beta^\complement.
$$

Since $A_\beta \ne \emptyset$, we must have $\mu(A_\beta) = 0$. Thus $\mu\left(\left(\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha\right)^\complement\right) = 0$ since $\mu$ is complete. It follows that the union of any collection of sets in $\mathcal J$ is also in $\mathcal J$.

Comment: In point 2., you have to treat the (trivial) case when at least one of the sets is empty separately. And in point 3., the case when all $A_\alpha$ are empty.

Comment: @DanielFischer I wanted to omit some details, but you're right; a hint should point this out. Edited now. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @AymanHourieh: 2) $\mu(A\cap B)^{c}=\mu(A^{c}\cup B^{c})=\mu(A^{c})+\mu(B^{c})=0\Rightarrow A\cap B\in \mathcal{J}$

Comment: @HeidiE We don't know if $A^\complement$, $B^\complement$ are disjoint or not. All what we can say is $\mu(A^\complement \cup B^\complement) \le \mu(A^\complement) + \mu(B^\complement) = 0$. But this still gives the desired result.

Comment: @AymanHourieh You are right, I missed that conditon. If $A=\emptyset$ then $\mu(\emptyset\cap B)^{c}=\mu(\emptyset^{c}\cup B^{c})\le \mu (\emptyset^{c})+\mu(B^{c})=0$ so $\emptyset\cap B=\emptyset \in \mathcal{J}$ right?

Comment: for the last condition: let $\{A_{\alpha}\}\in\mathcal{J}$ and $A_{\alpha}=\emptyset$, $\forall \alpha$ then $\displaystyle\bigcup_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}=\emptyset\in \mathcal{J}$. Let  $A_{\alpha}\neq\emptyset$, $\forall \alpha$ then $\mu(\bigcup_{\alpha}A_{\alpha})=\mu(\displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}^{c})=0$ so $\displaystyle\bigcup_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}\in \mathcal{J}$ Am I correct?

Comment: @HeidiE If $A = \emptyset$ then $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and we don't need to do any further checks. As for your other comment, be careful with quantifiers. We consider two cases: $\forall \alpha : A_\alpha = \emptyset$, and $\exists \alpha : A_\alpha \ne \emptyset$. In the first case, the union is empty too. In the second case, the measure of the intersection of complements is $0$.

Comment: Something perplexes me. Do we know that uncountable union of measurable sets is measurable? If not, the third step is problematic, no? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Arash A uncountable union is not necessarily measurable. However, this is not how we justify the measurability of $\left(\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha\right)^\complement$. Notice that $\left(\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha\right)^\complement = \bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha^\complement \subset A_\beta^\complement$ for any fixed $\beta$. Now $\mu(A_\beta^\complement) = 0$ and $\mu$ is complete. Thus, $\left(\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha\right)^\complement$ is measurable.

Comment: @HeidiE I expanded my answer to show the details.

Comment: @Arash I expanded my answer to show the details.

Comment: @AymanHourieh: many thanks for the help!

Comment: @HeidiE You're welcome!